# Are there known minimal models for the cohomology of semisimple Lie algebras?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, lie-algebras

My student and I recently found a cute construction of a minimal model for the cohomology of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. This is a "minimal model" in the sense that it is a minimal chain-homotopy deformation retract of the Chevalley-Eilenberg DGA of $\mathfrak{g}$. The point is that the minimal model is smaller than the Chevalley-Eilenberg DGA, quite small and easy to work with, and yet it has the same cohomology as the entire Chevalley-Eilenberg DGA, so it knows all about the cohomology of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If the ground field is of characteristic zero, then I suspect our model can also be viewed as a minimal model in the sense of Sullivan as well, although I haven't tried to prove that.

For a semisimple Lie algebra, this minimal model is especially small; for a nilpotent Lie algebra, on the other hand, the construction often yields the entire Chevalley-Eilenberg DGA, so it's not interesting.

We construct our minimal model in the course of doing something else, but we wonder if the construction might be of independent interest (or, on the other hand, if the construction is not new at all). We found nothing in the literature, but we do not know the Lie algebras literature well. Are there known minimal models for Lie algebras, in anything like the sense I described above? Have constructions of this kind already been studied?

Thanks, and I apologize if the question isn't right for this site.

Comment: Lie algebras are an example of algebras over a quadratic operad. There is a general theory of operadic homology which extends Lie algebra homology, and for "Koszul Lie algebras" there is an explicit formula for minimal models. This is alluded to in "Algebraic Operads" by Loday-Vallette, but not developed aside from for associative algebras. It is possible that semisimple Lie algebras fall into the category of Koszul Lie algebras, but it is surprisingly difficult to find exposition on these minimal models.